# fs and child_process not resolved in phantomjs-prebuilt

Tags: javascript, html, npm, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs-prebuilt for pdf conversion.But it required 'fs' and 'child_process' dependency.

```
ERROR in ./~/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantomjs.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in \node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib


ERROR in ./~/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantomjs.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'child_process'
```

Please help me to resolve these dependency.

Comment: When does this error occur?

Comment: on var phantomjs = require('phantomjs-prebuilt') line

Comment: i try var childProcess = require('child_process') and var fs= require('fs') line before but wont work

Comment: So it occurs when you run a script. May we see your script? Also, please, show how exactly you run it.

Comment: i am trying to run this code                                                                                  var path = require('path')
var childProcess = require('child_process')
var phantomjs = require('phantomjs-prebuilt')
var binPath = phantomjs.path
 
var childArgs = [
  path.join(__dirname, 'phantomjs-script.js'),
  'some other argument (passed to phantomjs script)'
]
 
childProcess.execFile(binPath, childArgs, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // handle results 
})

Comment: from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt

Comment: Please update your question with the script, it's hard to read it in the comment. Also, write about how you run this script. Like `node script.js` ? Also, have a look at this [q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41033162/2715393), could this be relevant to your case?