# reactjs - phantomjs-node issues with "fs" module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, phantomjs

I am trying to use phantomjs-node to capture screen. In my component i import `const phantom = require('phantom');`. Then after click i want to run method -

```
printOnePage(){
        phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
            ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
                page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
                    console.log(status);
                    page.property('content').then(function(content) {
                        console.log(content);
                        page.close();
                        ph.exit();
                    });
                });
            });
         });
}
```

But i am still gettint error -

```
webpack:///./~/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantomjs.js?:8 Uncaught Error:  Cannot find module "fs"(…)
```

Any tips what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a webpack misconfiguration. An [issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/8) on the error suggests that a block

```
node: {
  fs: "empty"
}
```

needs to be added to the webpack config. Another remedy, [it seems](https://github.com/josephsavona/valuable/issues/9#issuecomment-257203966), could be to add an option

```
target: 'node',
```

to the webpack config.